# What is the source of facebook logo image?

Tags: html, facebook, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

http://www.facebook.com homepage when displayed in firebug shows that the image/icon of "facebook" on the top left corner has the following HTML:

```
 <i class="fb_logo img sp_ezjerk sx_440431">
   <u>Facebook logo
   </u>
 </i>
```

Even the media resource list does not show any image/icon in png/ico/gif for the "facebook" image that appears.

I have tried searching for that logo source even in chrome developer tools, but I am unable to locate it.

Firstly, where does the text logo come from?

Secondly, why is it placed under the < i > tag which is primarily used for italicized text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick inspection of that `i` element shows the following CSS classes being applied:

```
img
sp_ezjerk
sx_440431
```

The latter two appear to be dynamically generated and change with each page load.

The first of the latter two, on each page load, shows the following CSS rules:

```
background-image: url("/rsrc.php/v2/yR/r/7TyBDSy09g8.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 104px 488px;
display: inline-block;
height: 32px;
width: 24px;
```

The image file at `/rsrc.php/v2/yR/r/7TyBDSy09g8.png` contains the logo, and the CSS is positioning it to display only that portion of the image.

As for why they chose an `i` element, that is beyond me.  I wouldn't have chosen it, but I guess they did.